# How to stop running my threads after a period of time?

Tags: python, shell, python-multithreading

I need to stop running my threads after a period of time, In this example I put only 120 seconds. I try by using this methods by it does not work.

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import os
import time

timeout = 120   # [seconds]

timeout_start = time.time()

#while True :


def OpenWSN ():
    os.system("./toto")

def Wireshark():
    os.system(" tshark -i tun0 -T ek -w /home/ptl/PCAP_Brouillon/Sim_Run3rd.pcap > /dev/null ")


def wrapper1(func, queue):
    queue.put(func())

def wrapper2(func, queue):
    queue.put(func())


q = Queue()
Thread(target=wrapper1, args=(OpenWSN, q)).start()
Thread(target=wrapper2, args=(Wireshark,  q)).start()

#print (time.time())
print ("***************** End Simulation *************************")
os.system("quit")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work" you're not referencing timeout nor timeout_start for one..

Comment: @Jaxi I put my timeout = 120

Comment: It does not work (I take that you simply don't see anything in console) because you have written `from Queue import Queue` instead of `from queue import Queue`.

Comment: As for the timeout - you are not using it, as log as I understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import os
import time

timeout = 120   # [seconds]

timeout_start = time.time()

def OpenWSN ():
    print( "OpenWSN:")
    os.system("echo -OpenWSN-")

def Wireshark():
    print( "Wireshark:")
    os.system("echo -Wireshark-")

def wrapper1(func, queue):
    queue.put(func())

def wrapper2(func, queue):
    queue.put(func())

q = Queue()
threading.Thread(target=wrapper1, args=(OpenWSN, q)).start()
threading.Thread(target=wrapper2, args=(Wireshark,  q)).start()

cv = threading.Condition()
cv.acquire()
cv.wait( timeout )

print ("***************** End Simulation *************************")
print (" Simulation Time: {0}s".format( time.time() - timeout_start) )

os.system("echo -exit-")
```

This produces the following output:

```
C:\temp\StackExchange\StopRunningThread>python -B stop-running-thread.py
OpenWSN:
Wireshark:
-OpenWSN-
-Wireshark-
***************** End Simulation ************************* 
Simulation Time: 120.04460144042969s
-exit-
```

What is happening there - you are starting two threads, each starts separate process in the system. After the said threads were started, you return to your main thread, allocate a "lock" and wait until this lock is signaled, or time out takes place.
In this particular case nobody signals the lock, so the only chance to finish the application is to wait until the time out happens.
I would extend your application that it signals the lock in each thread function, so we can terminate the main thread only if both of thread functions terminate. 
But that was not the part of your question, so I assume you can leave without signalling.

Comment: I validate  you answer. because it is correct, I have the wright execution. My only problem now is about the last instruction; instead of  os.system("echo -exit-")  I put os.system("echo  'quit\n' ") However it does not work. The execution of the program does not stop

Comment: It should be "exit", not "quit". `os.system( <your command here>)` invokes a command interpreter as if you were typing these commands in your command shell. Whatever you try to execute - test first by just running it in a command shell. Could be also useful - return value of `os.system()` call is what that command/program returns after it ends (program exist status). That is as if you were checking the `ERRNO` variable in the command shell after some command execution. It gives you an idea if and what went wrong.